# Reemplazar caracter en un campo mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo en una tabla un campo tipo texto en donde se ha cambiado la Ññ y las bocales con tilde por un signo de interrogacion (?) de tal manera que Explotacion aparece como Explotaci?n, compañias como Compa?as, etc. Es posible emitir una consulta `SQL` para reemplazar el caracter ? por el que corresponda en las 15683 filas?

Comment: Prueba cambiando el charset de la base de datos a utf8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Ponga un charset que admita los caracteres de su idioma, esto lo puede hacer al momento de hacer la conexión con su DB

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","userDB","passDB","yourDB")or die  ("<script language='JavaScript'>alert('No se puede conectar a la Base de Datos, Contacte a un administrador... !!!');window.location = '../../error.php';</script>");
mysqli_set_charset( $mysqli, 'utf8'); // <========== JUSTO ESTA LINEA DE CODIGO !!!!
/*if ($mysqli != true){
    echo 'Error en la cadena de conexion';
}*/
?>
```